# Latex for numpy boolean indexing

Tags: matrices, indexing, pseudocode

Assume mask is a length N boolean vector and x is a length N vector.  Using numpy fancy indexing i can write:

```
y = x[mask]
```

How can the above operation be shown clearly, formally, and concisely using latex (although probably not a concisely as numpy)?  Thank you

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: perhaps this is the wrong site for my question.  At this moment I don't need help with latex itself.  My question is really what should the result look like, what symbols should it use, etc.  So perhaps more suited to a math site?

Comment: please add some link to numpy doc (I used https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html as basis of my answer but it may not be what you mean)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xintexpr}

\begin{document}
\xintdefiivar Yarray := 1..100;

\xintdefiifunc Bmask(y) := y<10 'or' y > 50 'and' even(y) 'and' y==3*(y//3);

% one can also use y/:3 for the modulo, so `y==3*(y//3)` could be replaced by `not(y/:3)`.

\xintdefiivar Ymasked := seq(Bmask(y)?{y}{omit}, y=Yarray);

\xinttheiiexpr Ymasked\relax
\end{document}
```

[image]